# Quartz Cron expression with custom hours

Tags: cron, expression

I want to write a quartz cron expression that will fire my trigger in the following times:

7:40 AM, 1 PM, 6 PM.

I know that I can do this:

0 0,40 7,13,18 ? * 2-6 (to run it MON - FRI every day in the month)

But the problem is that it will actually run at 7:00, 7:40, 13:00, 13:40, 18:00, 18:30.

Please show me a best practice to such issue.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: You should probably have it on two separate lines, one for 7:40, and one for 13 and 18

Comment: Tnx mstbaum, but I thought there is a trick to do this.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything like "this minute with this hour and this minute with these hours" in a single line.  Also, Monday is 1.  You can also put `MON-FRI`

Comment: That's the whole point, I am trying exactly what you are talking about.
But if you say that it's impossible by design of cron, I will take your suggestion.
It's a bit strange that I don't have such functionality isn't it?